# i want to extract specific section from resume, CVs

Tags: python, nlp

I want to extract a specific section from a resume or CV...like education, experience. I did this but when education or any other section is written last in CV then it won't work.

```
` def extract_experience(ex_cl):   #create function of experience
     doc= fitz.open(ex_cl)   #open pdf file
     text=""             #crate string
     for page in doc:
     text= text + str(page.getText())  #conver pdf text into string
     words= nltk.word_tokenize(text)  #convert all text of CV into words

     start = 0
     end= 0

     #manually create [exp_list] which contain all CVs titles are possibel [not including 
     experience word](lan= german and English)

     exp_list=["FÄHIGKEITEN","KENNTNISSE","AUSBILDUNG","Ausbildung", "BILDUNG", "Bildung", 
                "Hobbies","HOBBIES","Personliche","Fahigkeiten",
                "Kenntnisse","Ehrenamtliches","Engagement",
                 "Sprachen","SPRACHEN","EHRENAMTLICHES",
                  "ENGAGEEMENT","EDUCATION" ,"Education","Hochschul",
                    "HOCHSCHUL","Studium","STUDIUM","Sprachkurse","Computerkenntnisse",
                  "SPRACHEN","SPRACHKURSE","COMPUTERKENNTNISSE", 
           "AWARDS","Awards","PERSONAL","Personal","Information", "INFORMATION",
           "SKILLS","Skills","SKILL","Skill",'Soziales']

     #manually create  [exp] list which contain experience title and also synonym words of 
     experiance word


     exp=['Erfahrung' ,'Laufbahn','ERFAHRUNG' ," Erfahrungen" ,'LAUFBAHN','Praktische',
                                                           
          'PRAKTISCHE','ERFAHRUNGEN','Praktika','PRAKTIKA' ,
         'Berufserfahrung' ,'EXPERIENCE','Experience' ,'BERÜFSERFAHRUNG','Berufserfahrung']

     for vari in words:        # Match experience word or synonym word from CV and manually 
                                                         created list[exp]  
        if vari in exp:         # if match then find index of that word
          st=words.index(vari)
          start= st+1           #(st+1)for take next word  
                            # get index of experience word of CV
          i = start             #give another variable(i)
     for j in words:                          #create for loop
        if words[i]  not in exp_list:   #if  start index is not in [exp_list(without 
                                                             experience 
                                                                                       word)] 
           i += 1                        #then take next index untill it match the word 
                                                                       of[exp_list]
           end= start+(i-start)               # find end index 
      
 
    

      f_list=[]  #create list
      for item in words[start:end]: #give slicing for take start index and end index
         f_list.append(item)  #append into list
      stringlist = ' '.join(f_list )  #convert into string


      return stringlist

extract_experience('020.pdf')
```

`

Comment: Provide full working code as a minimal example. Link the PDF to the question so someone can use it to reproduce what you describe in your question. End of Review.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Tika to extract the text from the pdf first. It helps collate the text correctly. But to extract the sections will require some dirty code.

Something I'd try is to extract sections based on multiple newline (/n/n or more). A dirtier route would be to cut out sections based on heuristics like

- create of list of possible title sections
- loop  through the text
- if title section:

  - start counting from that index up until it meets another section title capitalised or in upper case (this helps avoid cases like skills vs Skills or SKILLS)
    Like I mentioned - dirty

A probably cleaner approach is to use NER (Named Entity Recognition) with SpaCy. But you'll have to create a dataset of CVs and manually label each section.

See [this repo](https://github.com/laxmimerit/Resume-and-CV-Summarization-and-Parsing-with-Spacy-in-Python) using NER to extract information needed

Comment: ..euhm... nice to layout an approach route to tackle something outside the scripting language OP is using. In short, it doesn't solve OPs problem yet. Can you help with the code? If so you get a quality answer and no down-votes for not solving the question, rather than starting a discussion. End of Review.

Comment: I don't have the time to write all the code. I can send the link to a repo that used SpaCy for the data extraction

Comment: Not sure if that is what OP is waiting for but it will improve answer quality. Update your answer with such information is preferred over posting in comments.